# Application deployed inside an application's virtual directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have a virtual directory which runs a ASP.Net Web application.

It is located at C:\Data

I access it using the URL - http://data.com

I have added one more virtual directory insider C:\Data\NewData New Data is made an application root too.

When I try to access a page using the URL http://data.com/NewData/Default.aspx I get an error -

> ### Server Error in '/XXXXXXXXXX' Application.
>
> Configuration Error  Description: An error occurred during the
>   processing of a configuration file required to service this request.
>   Please review the specific error details below and modify your
>   configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The entry 'ScriptModule' has already been added.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 96:
>
> Line 97:      Line 98:       
>   Line 99:

The problem is with Web.Config, ie. the Web.Config related to a directory up in the hierarchy is used. Is there any to solve the issue?

I have checked http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx too. But did not get a clue on how to override parental configurations.

Answer (score 1):

In your web.config, under `<httpModules>` add the line:

```
 <clear />
```

That will clear any existing module definitions inherited from up the tree.

Comment: @DavidStratton I need the rep more! ;)

Comment: Adding  <clear /> solved the problem with HTTP modules, but get one new one with SQLServer Session State. The issue now is: "Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the <configuration>\<system.web>\<httpModules> section in the application configuration. " And SQLServerSessionState is disabled at the Parent Virtual Directory Level.

Comment: @PriyaranjanAnandMarathe You can do that with most of the sections which ave multiple values.

Comment: There must be another way to clear the element for this tag. Because I get - Unrecognized configuration section system.web/clear.

when I added  <clear /> tag before the  <sessionState mode="SQLServer" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true"... item.

Comment: @PriyaranjanAnandMarathe Check out this post:http://blogs.iis.net/steveschofield/archive/2009/09/19/control-web-config-inheritance-with-iis-7-asp-net-options.aspx  I would suggest one of the first two options here in order to just prevent the inheritance.

Comment: @PriyaranjanAnandMarathe No, you can't put it directly in the <system.web> element, but you can do it in in like <connectionStrings>, <httpHandlers>, etc.

Comment: Okay. I will check it today once I am on my home network. Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4208/discussion-between-priyaranjan-anand-marathe-and-coding-gorilla)